# Create NSSplitView + subview programmatically

Tags: cocoa, nssplitview

I am trying to create a horizontal `NSSplitView` programmatically and to add it 2 subviews.
Unfortunately, if I have no issue to create the splitview, I do not know how to add the subview.

Do you have any idea to do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You add panes to a split view the same way you add subviews to any view. Each of the split view's subviews will get its own pane. You can use the `adjustSubviews` method to automatically resize the views so that each pane is the same size.

This example code will create a split view which fills its window and has 3 text views split vertically.

```
NSSplitView *splitView = [[NSSplitView alloc] initWithFrame:[[theWindow contentView] bounds]];
NSTextView *textView1 = [NSTextView new];
NSTextView *textView2 = [NSTextView new];
NSTextView *textView3 = [NSTextView new];
[splitView addSubview:textView1];
[splitView addSubview:textView2];
[splitView addSubview:textView3];
[splitView adjustSubviews];
[[theWindow contentView] addSubview:splitView];
[textView3 release];
[textView2 release];
[textView1 release];
[splitView release];
```

Comment: Thanks [splitView adjustSubviews]; was the missing part!

Comment: adjustSubviews doesn't do it for me